Cloud Scheduler Crons Failing Only in Staging Environment (No Logs)
Context:
I have two environments, prod and staging, that are mostly identical (prod just has a larger Cloud SQL DB instance). In both environments, I use Cloud Scheduler crons set to run every minute ("* * * * *") and trigger Cloud Run batch jobs.
Problem:
In recent weeks, and only in the staging environment, Cloud Scheduler crons are regularly failing to run, usually for a few minutes in a row but sometimes for periods of up to an hour.
During these gaps:

There are no logs in Cloud Scheduler (no successes or failures). (protoPayload.@type="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog")
Cloud Run job logs show no activity during the gap (no job starts, or fails to start)

After the gap:

Cloud Run logs show a bunch of "Execution {id} has been deleted." messages.

Troubleshooting Performed:
I checked all of the easy things:

cron expressions are correct
no quota seems to be hit (or even close)
permissions are OK

Question:
What could be causing Cloud Scheduler crons to silently fail/pause ? What could cause it to happen only in the staging environment?
I'm at a loss for further troubleshooting steps. Any insights or suggestions on how to diagnose the root cause of these cron jobs not launching would be greatly appreciated.

Any specific error message or error code? Have you checked this documentation on running services on a schedule if you're running Cloud Run service or execute jobs on a schedule if you're running Cloud Run jobs as you may have missed some steps?

Yep, I have (in fact, 99.9% of the time several jobs are running on a schedule perfectly fine).
No error message or errors codes either, it's just: a cron should run, and doesn't.
Mind you, I might be within the Cloud Scheduler SLA (1h of crons not running would be 99.95% over the month) - but I'm puzzled that it's happening repeatedly, in one project only.

Have you also tried deploying a fresh Cloud Run service or job to check whether the issue would appear again?

Yes, whenever the issue happens, it happens for all of the scheduler jobs in the project (the fact that the callee is a cloud run job does not seem to be material to the issue).
